RabbitMQ overflow buffer/cache memory
im first time here :) The server hosting RabbitMQ is constantly consuming cache and buffer and continues to grow. The message flow has not increased. After reaching the limit, the service goes down.
RabbitMQ screenshot
In RabbitMQ config set watermark 0.4

you say message flow has not increased, but that's not relevant. Seems to me that messages are produced faster than they are consumed. You should check on this issue.

I meant rabbitmq started consuming more RAM not because of the larger stream of incoming messages that would have to be processed.

Stack Overflow is Q&A format (one focused question, answered by a vareity of other users), what is your actual question here?

I'm unsure what you are expecting in this case. Did you expect RabbitMQ to behave differently in this cas ? If so, why and how?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
